# Ставить ли запятую в предложении «На первом этаже(,) у входа»?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

«На первом этаже(,) у входа».

Нужна ли запятая? Является ли это уточнением?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обособление факультативное, авторское, зависит от структуры предложения, распространенности обстоятельства и других факторов:

(1) На первом этаже, **у входа в ночной клуб**, уже стояла толпа (уточняющие обстоятельства места).

(2) Они договорились встретиться **на первом этаже у входа в ночной клуб** (неоднородные обстоятельства, обозначают разные координаты).